# My pet still attacks even when set to "Passive" mode?

Tags: torchlight

I am playing  as an Alchemist and my pet is a dog. I have already set its status to "Passive Stance", but it still attacks at times. (I think when it's getting hit by monsters). Is there a way to completely make him passive (no attacking at all)?

EDIT:
Just to clarify, the pet attacks regardless of stance (Aggressive, Defensive, Passive) it attacks even if the enemies haven't spotted us or haven't started attacking at all and are just idly walking around. I'm still looting on one area ten the pet runs off to attack enemies that aren't even on my screen yet. It's like he's stuck on Aggressive mode.

Comment: Mainly I am curious about this, why do you never want your pet to attack? I can understand having it on passive, bsince you don't want it to pull enemies on accident. But do you dislike your pet so much that you would rather have it die than defend itself when being attacked?

Comment: It's not that. I've already tried setting it to Defend but even so, it still keeps attacking enemies. They aren't even super close. He just goes out of is way to go there and attack. It's really annoying also if I want to let him regenerate health first. Because as soon as he has a small amount of HP, he starts attacking again then starts fleeing when the enemies are too much for him.

Comment: If enemies are within range of hitting you, and are trying to, your pet will attack them on defensive. The pet is trying to defend you. Where as the aggressive stance the pet will roam out and attack any enemies it sees.  If you just want your pet to stay behind you need to have it on passive, but it will defend itself.

Comment: I do have it on Passive but even if enemies are not attacking us at  all, he still attacks. :( I have edited my question to add further clarifications.

Comment: Can you post screenshot of the pet bar?